# File Cannot be downloaded

Tags: c#

Please Review My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace NGH_V1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello. Welcome to NGH's 1st Console Application. To Continue, Please Press Enter.");
            string option = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to download the VIP Trainer.Press 2 for Coming Soon!.", option);

            int result;

            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))

            {

                if (result == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading The Trainer!", option);
                    string remoteUri = "https://nukleus.XXX.com/dashboard/download/Trainer/XXXVIP.CETRAINER";
                    string fileName = XXXVIP.CETRAINER", myStringWebResource = null;
                    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                    myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
                }

                else if (result == 2)

                    Console.WriteLine("Info to be released later, ", option);

                else

                    Console.WriteLine("No Such Option!");

            }

            else

                Console.WriteLine("No Such Option!");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

When I Run the code and press 1; I get the following error: System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.' However, when i browse the exact same url via the browser, it downloads the file just fine. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your `string fileName` line looks...weird.

Comment: what can i do to see if it is and if it is, how can i fix it?

Comment: yes, the XXX is to replace the actual file name and the url of the file.

Comment: That's not the weird part.

Comment: then what is? string fileName = XXXVIP.CETRAINER" is the name for what it would be called when the file is downloaded.

Comment: It won't compile.  You don't have matching quotes.

Comment: I'm reading myStringWebResource as `...Trainer/XXXVIP.CETRAINERXXXVIP.CETRAINER`  Do I have that right?

Comment: Take a look at the final URI you're passing into `DownloadFile`. A 500 for what should be a 404 seems off, so it may not be your whole problem, but it's a place to start.

Comment: quotes? only the first part needs to be in quotes.

Comment: I don't see what your talking about???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 problems with the code:
string filename's value should start with double quotes,
what I mean is 
string filename = "XXXVIP.CETRAINER"

Assuming that we you have done this in your actual code, then the value of the variable myStringWebResource would be https://nukleus.XXX.com/dashboard/download/Trainer/XXXVIP.CETRAINERXXXVIP.CETRAINER which you are passing to download the file.

If your filename is XXXVIP.CETRAINER then the URL should simply be
https://nukleus.XXX.com/dashboard/download/Trainer/XXXVIP.CETRAINER

so essentially the code should look like:

```
if (result == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading The Trainer!", option);
                string remoteUri = "https://nukleus.XXX.com/dashboard/download/Trainer/XXXVIP.CETRAINER";
                string fileName = "XXXVIP.CETRAINER";
                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, remoteUri);
                myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, remoteUri);
            }
```